# How to get the type of Primitive from a declared class in Java?

Tags: java

I am not sure if my title describes exactly what I am trying to say - but here is what I am trying to do:

I have this class Numbers:

```
public class Numbers{

    private int Integers;
    private float Floaters;

    public Numbers(String xUserInput){

        if (xUserInput.matches("[0-9]+")) {

            System.out.println("Integer");
            try{
                this.setIntegers(Integer.parseInt(xUserInput));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(xUserInput + " is not of Integer type!");
            }

        } else if (xUserInput.matches("[0-9]*[.]{1}[0-9]+")) {

            System.out.println("Float");
            try{
                this.setFloaters(Float.parseFloat(xUserInput));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(xUserInput + " is not of Float type!");
            }

        } else {

            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
        }
    }

    public int getIntegers() {
        return this.Integers;
    }

    public void setIntegers(int integers) {
        this.Integers = integers;
    }

    public float getFloaters() {
        return this.Floaters;
    }

    public void setFloaters(float floaters) {
        this.Floaters = floaters;
    }
```

Now, in main - I add all user input in an ArrayList - but then I want to print the array twice, once with all integers, and then with all floaters.

How do I get to the primitive type? Please let me know where am I going wrong.

PS: I tried

```
for(Numbers n : numberList) {

        System.out.println(n.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
```

... but all i get is "Numbers."

Comment: What do you mean "primitive type"? What is the exact String you want to get returned instead of "Numbers"?

Comment: @Jj Thank you for the reply. I wanted to get "int" or "float" depending on what that entry was saved of.

Comment: If you down vote please - take the time to write a short comment so I can learn something from it.

Answer (score 0):

You always displaying the class name in loop. I guess what you want is:

```
// first loop
for(Numbers n : numberList) {
    System.out.println(n.getIntegers());
}

// second loop
for(Numbers n : numberList) {
    System.out.println(n.getFloaters());
}
```

Comment: That will print values but not type. Other types will display as 0. It is not exactly what I want.

Comment: So if I understand correctly Numbers can either be int or float and you want to only display that value?

Comment: The Type not the value itself i.e. int or float.

Comment: So add a new field as String type = "not set"; and set it as type = "int" when you set an integer or set it as type = "float" when you set a float and primt that field with a getter like getType().

Comment: I understand the work around - but it does not answer my question here.